# Finding the path & product version of a file in powershell

Tags: powershell, version, path-finding, file-find

I am try to create Powershell script to search for a sacrifice file (.exe) on the same machine or another machine in the network and return all the paths of the files with the product version for each one

I used the below code but I only was able to get the path only

`$filename = 'example.exe'`

`(gdr -PSProvider 'FileSystem' | %{ ls -r $_.root} 2>$null | where { $_.name -eq ".EXE" })`

Answer (score 0):

```
(gdr -PSProvider 'FileSystem' | %{ ls -r $_.root} 2>$null | where { $_.name -eq "$filename" } | Select FullName,@{n='Version';e={$_.versioninfo.productversion}})
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.